# AngularJS: Get additional infos depending from the chosen option in select-box

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm an AngularJS beginner.

The issue: I have a select box, built from a JSON. When I select an option, I can display the selected item. But additionally, I would like to display additional information.

My JSON looks like this

```
[
    { id : 1, name : "Notebooks", "products" : [
        { id : 101, name : "Lenovo 123",   "price" : 1299.9, "additionals" : 
            [ { id : 10001, name : "4GB RAM", "price": 100 },
              { id : 10002, name : "128GB SSD", "price" : 120 },
              { id : 10003, name : "120GB SSD", "price" : 120 },
              { id : 10004, name : "512GB SSD", "price" : 410 },
              { id : 10005, name : "External HDD", "price" : 80 }
            ] 
        }, 
        { id : 102, name : "Asus 456",   "price" : 1699.9, "additionals" : 
            [ { id : 20001, name : "4GB RAM", "price": 100 },
              { id : 20002, name : "256GB SSD", "price" : 140 },
              { id : 20003, name : "i7 CPU", "price" : 150 },
              { id : 20004, name : "512GB SSD", "price" : 440 },
              { id : 20005, name : "Windows 8.1", "price" : 100 }
            ]   
        }, 
        { id : 103, name : "Macbook Pro", "price" : 1949.0, "additionals" : 
            [ { id : 30001, name : "USB device", "price": 60 },
              { id : 30002, name : "External HDD", "price" : 80 },
              { id : 30003, name : "4GB RAM", "price" : 140 },
              { id : 30004, name : "512GB SSD", "price" : 300 },
              { id : 30005, name : "Mouse", "price" : 50 }
            ]   
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id : 2, name : "TVs", "products" : [
            { id : 501, name : "Samsung TV 1", "price": 959.9 },
            { id : 502, name : "Sony TV 2", "price": 1409.9 },
            { id : 503, name : "Philips TV 3", "price": 1899.9 }
        ]
    }
];
```

And my select box like this

```
<select id="product-selector" data-ng-model="product">
   <option value="0"></option>
    <optgroup data-ng-repeat="s in stock" label="{{ s.name }}">
        <option data-ng-repeat="p in s.products" 
           value="{{ p.id }}">{{ p.name }}</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Whatever I select, i wanna see more information like price, name, additionals, etc.

How can I do this in AngularJS? Probably this is really easy, but I guess I am on the wrong path.

I've tried multiple solutions, but none of them worked. I've created a fiddle for my last attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/kxx5a2ez/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the docs on how to use select correctly in angular: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: Thanks, how could I not find this? It's really easy, I just reformatted the JSON and adapted the code from the doc now it's like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kxx5a2ez/19/